# Python: re.sub removing words between two delimiters under different cases

Tags: python, string, python-re

I have a string that contains patterns like

```
"something [[remove|keep]] something [[keep]] something [[remove|remove|keep]] something"
```

How can I use `re.sub()` or other methods to edit this string to

```
"something keep something keep something keep something"
```

or

```
"something [[keep]] something [[keep]] something [[keep]] something".
```

(I can remove the `[[ ]]`s afterward.)

I tried using for-loop to hard code it, but the string is too long and takes a long time to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the regular expression: `(?<=[\[\|])[^\[]*?\|`:

```
import re

s = "something [[remove|keep]] something [[keep]] something [[remove|remove|keep]] something"
print(re.sub("(?<=[\[\|])[^\[]*?\|", "", s))
```

Output:

```
something [[keep]] something [[keep]] something [[keep]] something
```

The regular expression `(?<=[\[\|])[^\[]*?\|` can be broken down into three parts to return substrings that...

- `(?<=[\[\|])` - immediately to the left of the substring is a `[` or `|`
- `[^\[]*?` - contains anything *(non-greedy)* that is not a `[`
- `\|` - and ends with `|`